# ! Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit because of >{\raggedleft}?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I'm trying to create some T-account-tables. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,draft,oneside,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[natural,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\tableTAccount}[4]{
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{#1}
\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{
p{1.27cm}
p{0.69cm}
p{1.8cm}
p{2cm}
>{\raggedleft}p{1.55cm}|
p{1.27cm}
p{0.69cm}
p{1.8cm}
p{2cm}
>{\raggedleft}p{1.55cm}
}
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Soll} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{#2} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{Haben} \\ \hline
    #3
    \multicolumn{5}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{r}{} \\
    #4
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
}

\newcommand{\addRowTTA}[2]{#1 & #2 \\}

\newcommand{\addRowEntryTTA}[5]{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5}

\newcommand{\addRowEmptyEntryTTA}{&&&&}

\newcommand{\addRowTTAResults}[3]{
\multicolumn{5}{r|}{#1} & \multicolumn{5}{r}{#2} \\
\multicolumn{5}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{r}{#3} \\
}

\begin{document}

\tableTAccount
{T-Account}
{account}
{
\addRowTTA
    {\addRowEmptyEntryTTA}
    {\addRowEntryTTA{1}{2}{3}{4}{12.36}}
}
{\addRowTTAResults{0}{12.36}{12.36}}

\end{document}
```

resulting in:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
               \@multispan 
l.56     {\addRowTTAResults{0}{12.36}{12.36}}
```

When I swap the following lines

```
{\addRowEntryTTA{1}{2}{3}{4}{12.36}} 
{\addRowEmptyEntryTTA}
```

it works. But i want to be able, to use every possible combination out of \addRowEntryTTA and \addRowEmptyEntryTTA to build multiple \addRowTTA.

If I don't use >{\raggedleft} it works too, but I need to have a certain layout.

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\raggedleft` redefines `\\` to mean a ragged text line break and so that stops it having its end of table row meaning.

Either use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` to end the table row (this is the saved normal definition of `\\` inside tables) or use  `\raggedleft\arraybackslash`  then you can use `\\` again as `\arraybackslash` redefines `\\` to have its array/tabular meaning.