# "misplaced \omit" error when >{\centering} columns

Tags: tables, formatting

First of all, I have looked at every other `misplaced \omit...` error question about tables I have found on this site and none of them quite relate to my situation.  [This is the closest I could find](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415878/115653), but it does not quite fit my application the solution relates to using `\tabularnewline` vs `\\` in cells which I am not using.

---

I am attempting to make a table which looks *almost* like this:

[image]

The above example was generated from the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{m{1in}m{1in}m{1in}}
\cline{1-1}
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1in}|}{\textbf{Caption}} & cell of muliline text to wrap & cell of muliline text to wrap \\ \cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{m{1in}|}{cell of muliline text to wrap} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1in}|}{\textbf{Caption}} & cell of muliline text to wrap \\ \cline{2-3} 
cell of muliline text to wrap & \multicolumn{1}{m{1in}|}{cell of muliline text to wrap} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1in}|}{\textbf{Caption}} \\ \cline{3-3} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, I would like the columns to be centered instead of justified.  I would normally do this by replacing all instances of `m{1in}` with `>{\centering}m{1in}`.  But when I do this I get the following error.

```
! misplaced \omit.\@cline #1-#2\@nil -> ...
```

How do I reproduce the above table format but with centered columns?

Comment: Use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}` in the last column, or end every row with `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\ `.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}}}
\cline{1-1}
\multicolumn{1}{|m{1in}|}{\textbf{Caption}} & cell of muliline text to wrap & cell of muliline text to wrap \\ \cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{m{1in}|}{cell of muliline text to wrap} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1in}|}{\textbf{Caption}} & cell of muliline text to wrap \\ \cline{2-3} 
cell of muliline text to wrap & \multicolumn{1}{m{1in}|}{cell of muliline text to wrap} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1in}|}{\textbf{Caption}} \\ \cline{3-3} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

within the scope of `\centering`, `\\` is redefined to make a centred forced line break, so no longer has its "end table row" definition. You can either use `\arraybackslash` to re-assert the table definition of `\\` or you could use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` which is a longer form provided that always refers to the end of table row.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I was misinterpreting your answer to the linked question.